# How do I keep a request alive?

Tags: python, python-requests, keep-alive

I want to scrape a site but I need to wait in the site 30 seconds to get what I am looking for.

That's what I got now:

```
import requests

url = 'https://sheldon.sdarot.tv/w/SD/480/57/153183/153183.mp4?token=Gfc7vmObqcRRjiJKSgwJnQ&time=1622659950&uid=457724'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://' + "185.169.198.98:3128",
    'https': 'http://' + "185.169.198.98:3128",
}

s = requests.Session()

r = s.get(url, verify=True, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `time.sleep(30)`

Comment: Your usecase may be better suited to something like `selenium`

Comment: To be specific, remember that `requests` can only deliver to you the text on the original page.  If the page changes in your browser, that's because there is Javascript code running that is changing the page.  You aren't running the Javascript, so you'll never see that change, no matter how long you wait.  If you need Javascript, then you need a real browser, and that's what `selenium` does.

Answer (score 0):

you get a response from the server so there is no way for you as a client to bypass their auth.
token=Ym8kbsZ0FjVJisOJlA-C5A: this is the approval for the time you waited.
you may try using selenium to automate the waiting time for you but thats it